N1QL query issue in Couchbase lite SQL++ for Mobile
I have a couchbase collection called “books” in “cloud” scope. This is the document structure -
{
    "doc_type": "book_item",
    "plumap": {
        "000": {
            "title": "To Kill a Mockingbird"
        },
        "000": {
            "title": "Pride and Prejudice"
        },
    }
}

I want to search for books by title. This query is working in couchbase server.
SELECT * FROM bucket.cloud.books AS d WHERE d.doc_type = 'book_item' AND ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(d.plumap) SATISFIES v.title LIKE '%mock%' END LIMIT 5

I want to do the same on Android with SQL++ for mobile but I’m getting this error “N1QL syntax error near character 96” which is the parenthesis “(” after OBJECT_VALUES. How can I fix the syntax?
Or if it’s possible to get this through QueryBuilder is also fine.
